# expression engine sql query entries list by authors

Tags: sql, expressionengine

How would I order the latest 3 entries from a channel with each entry from a different author? (so they don't end up being 3 latest entries by the same author)  - I think I need to use an SQL Query for it?

```
{exp:channel:entries orderby="screen_name|date" channel="portfolios" limit="3" group_id="5" dynamic="no"}
<img src=" {thumbnail}" alt="{title}"/><br />
{title}<br />
{/exp:channel:entries}
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Mark - here's a repost of the answer I posted on the [other dupe question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7067695/expression-engine-sql-query-help-latest-posts-by-author):

---

The best approach here, since you need your custom fields parsed, is to first find the entry_ids of the latest 4 entries from distinct authors, and then pass those to the `channel:entries` tag through an embed using the `entry_id` parameter.

This should work (be sure to replace the `channel_id` with the appropriate integer). Replace your entire current chunk of code with this:

```
{embed="embeds/_latest_per_member" entry_ids="{exp:query sql="SELECT entry_id, author_id FROM exp_channel_titles WHERE entry_date IN( SELECT MAX(entry_date) FROM exp_channel_titles  WHERE status != 'closed' AND channel_id = 1 GROUP BY author_id ) ORDER BY entry_date DESC LIMIT 4" backspace="1"}{entry_id}|{/exp:query}"}
```

Then your **embeds/_latest_per_member** template can look something like this:

```
{exp:channel:entries channel="channel_name" entry_id="{embed:entry_ids}"}
    {author_id}<br />
    <a href="{path=portfolios/gallery/{username}}"><img src="{thumbnail}"></a><br>
    <a href="{path=portfolios/gallery/{username}}">{title}</a><br />
{/exp:channel:entries}
```

You had mentioned that this code gave you a recursive error - that means that you've put another call to the embed *within* the embed. Don't do that.

Comment: Thanks Derek - I think that works - There is no way I would have figured that out - is status! ee code or sql? does it mean 'not'? what does the backspace=1 do?

Comment: `!=` means "does not equal" ... it's a non-trivial SQL query overall to be sure, but that's the power of EE - you can do pretty much anything with the right query. For more info on the `backspace` parameter [look here](http://expressionengine.com/user_guide/modules/channel/parameters.html#par_backspace) (many EE module tags use it in exactly the same way).

Comment: what is the backspace removing? seems to work ok if I remove it. is it the | ? does the IN(select MAX find the latest entry date? agree EE is powerful but finding support in the forums really lacking these days. Not a lot of SQL Query examples in there either.

Comment: Yes, the backspace removes the pipe, but I suppose without it it just adds an extra empty entry_id, which is harmless. The IN([subquery]) is what selects the latest entry grouped by author, which is then ordered chronologically by the main query.

Comment: This query takes over 30 seconds to go over 20K entries

Comment: @GDmac I'd expect as much, sure.

Answer (score 1):

The WHERE IN (SELECT MAX(entry_date)...) example took a huge hit at the database. It seems to essentially do a subquery for each entry. An alternative i found ([Stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16307932/25286)) uses just one subquery in the FROM part,

quote: *Do a GROUP BY after the ORDER BY by wrapping your query with the GROUP BY* :-).

Anyway ... This fetches all authors and their last posted entry title. If you also want the url_title, you have to add it to both SELECT statements. I've included some extra options,  fetch only for the last 4 months, limited to channel_id 8, and limit to category_id 68.

```
SELECT author_id, screen_name, title, FROM_UNIXTIME(entry_date) AS m_date 
FROM (
  SELECT t.author_id, t.title, m.screen_name, t.entry_date
  FROM exp_channel_titles AS t
  LEFT JOIN exp_members AS m ON t.author_id = m.member_id
  LEFT JOIN exp_category_posts AS c ON c.entry_id = t.entry_id
  WHERE t.entry_date > UNIX_TIMESTAMP(DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 4 MONTH)) 
  AND t.channel_id = 8
  AND c.cat_id = 68
  ORDER BY t.entry_date DESC
) AS S 
GROUP BY S.author_id
ORDER BY entry_date DESC
# LIMIT 10
```