# Expression Engine SQL Query help - latest posts by author

Tags: sql, expressionengine

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [expression engine sql query entries list by authors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7047022/expression-engine-sql-query-entries-list-by-authors)

I’m trying to create a short sidebar list of latest posts from a channel, with each post by a separate author.
Could someone help as regards merging these queries I think I have (sort of) working separately?

format:

```
screen name
thumbnail
title
```

this query code creates a list, but with author_id rather than screen name 
title works ok, but the thumbnail doesn’t load and the path doesn’t write properly.

```
{exp:query sql="SELECT t.title, t.author_id FROM exp_channel_titles t 
ORDER BY author_id ASC LIMIT 4"}
{author_id}<br />
<a href="{path=portfolios/gallery/{username}}"><img src="{thumbnail}"></a><br>
<a href="{path=portfolios/gallery/{username}}">{title}</a><br />
{/exp:query}
```

This query code create the path properly and the user name properly but the title is just appearing as {title}
thumbnail doesn’t load.

```
{exp:query sql="SELECT m.member_id, m.username, m.screen_name, m.avatar_filename FROM exp_members m 
WHERE m.group_id='5' "}
{screen_name}
<a href="{path=portfolios/gallery/{username}}"><img src="{thumbnail}"></a><br>
<a href="{path=portfolios/gallery/{username}}">{title}</a><br />
 {/exp:query}
```

I presume I need to use a JOIN but I’m really not that expert with SQL queries.

thumbnail is a field in exp_channel_fields - any idea how I get this into the query?
the filename for the image is in exp_channel_data but it is like this -

```
{filedir_1}13.jpg
```

how do I get rid of the

```
{filedir_1}
```

bit or create a path?

or should I be using {exp:channel: in there as well ?

Answer (score 0):

The best approach here, since you need your custom fields parsed, is to first find the entry_ids of the latest 4 entries from distinct authors, and then pass those to the `channel:entries` tag through an embed using the `entry_id` parameter.

This should work (be sure to replace the `channel_id` with the appropriate integer):

```
{embed="embeds/_latest_per_member" entry_ids="{exp:query sql="SELECT entry_id, author_id FROM exp_channel_titles WHERE entry_date IN( SELECT MAX(entry_date) FROM exp_channel_titles  WHERE status != 'closed' AND channel_id = 1 GROUP BY author_id ) ORDER BY entry_date DESC LIMIT 4" backspace="1"}{entry_id}|{/exp:query}"}
```

Then your **embeds/_latest_per_member** template can look something like this:

```
{exp:channel:entries channel="channel_name" entry_id="{embed:entry_ids}"}
    {author_id}<br />
    <a href="{path=portfolios/gallery/{username}}"><img src="{thumbnail}"></a><br>
    <a href="{path=portfolios/gallery/{username}}">{title}</a><br />
{/exp:channel:entries}
```

Comment: thanks derek - but I get the message 'You have caused a template loop due to improperly nested sub-templates ('embeds/latest_per_member' recursively called)'. Here's my basic EE code that works but doesn't show posts 1 per author - it shows posts by all authors if it helps. `<h3/>Latest Entries<h3>
{exp:channel:entries channel="portfolios" orderby="date"  ASC limit="3" group_id="5" dynamic="no"}
{entry_date format="%j %M %Y"}<br />
<a href="{path=portfolios/gallery2/{username}}">{exp:ce_img:single src="{thumbnail}" height="112" width="150" crop="yes"} </a><br />
{/exp:channel:entries}`

Comment: I actually created a new question here [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7081316/expressionengine-latest-entries-by-author) as  I thought it might make it simpler to explain

Comment: Mark - continue on [this thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7047022/expression-engine-sql-query-entries-list-by-authors).