# MySQL - using GROUP BY and DESC

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by, sql-order-by

In my SQL query I am selecting data with **GROUP BY** and **ORDER BY** clauses. The table has the same `numbers` across multiple rows with different times in each row. So I think I want to apply a **GROUP BY** clause.

However in the results return the oldest time with the number, but I need the most recent time.

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE GROUP BY (numbers) ORDER BY time DESC
```

The query appears as if it should first apply **GROUP BY** and then **ORDER BY**... but the results do not appear to work this way.

Is there any way to fix this?

Comment: [In the docs](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/group-by-hidden-columns.html) the behaviour you get if you select columns that are not grouped by is explicitly called out as "indeterminate" in the event that they have multiple values per group. You can't rely on any particular behaviour. Do you need the whole row or just `numbers, max(time)`

Comment: Can you provide some rows of data with the result you expect ?

Comment: Thanks guys, you moved me to the right direction.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1066453/mysql-group-by-and-order-by

Answer (score 18, accepted):

work-around is to re-write the query as:

```
SELECT * FROM (SELECT * FROM table ORDER BY time DESC) AS t GROUP BY numbers;
```

Comment: In theory you cannot guarantee that you will always get the same result.

Comment: @Karolis agreed, your answer seems to be the more correct one

Comment: This uses a MySQL extension to `group by` that is explicitly documented not work reliably:  http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-extensions.html.

Comment: @GordonLinoff I guess this is why it didn't work for me, thanks for mentioning that

Comment: @GordonLinoff Link is broken. Any idea for what I should be searching for? Thanks

Comment: @Houman . . . How strange.  You can use the 8.0 version:  https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/group-by-handling.html.

Comment: @GordonLinoff Thank you for the link, Strange this answer doesn't seem to work on MariaDB 10.0.34. I will keep searching...

Comment: @Houman . . . This answer is wrong and should not have been accepted.  Use the answer by Karolis.

Comment: @GordonLinoff I found it why it stopped working. the version 5.7.5 of MySQL made the ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY switch enabled by default (hence, non-deterministic GROUP BY queries became disabled). Moreover, they updated the GROUP BY implementation and the solution might not work as expected anymore even with the disabled switch. :-(

Comment: @Houman it seems that non-deterministic GROUP BY gives the same results when ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY is disabled. See this demo https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/esww483qFQXbXzJmkHZ8VT/3 (you can switch MySQL versions at the left side and result is the same including 5.7 and 8.0).

Answer (score 22):

```
SELECT * 
FROM table t
WHERE time = (
    SELECT max(time)
    FROM table
    WHERE t.numbers = numbers
)
```

Comment: When I try to run this query on a dummy table, somehow I end up getting all the rows. Removing the WHERE inside subquery works for me, however.

Answer (score 3):

```
SELECT * FROM table
    WHERE time IN (
        SELECT MAX(time)
            FROM table
            GROUP BY numbers
    )
```

Comment: Code only answers are usually [frowned upon](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/258673/2596334). Try adding an [explination or code comments](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/269981/2596334). Thanks.

Comment: No, we can't look at group wise maximums as a set of unrelated data. For instance this query fails here: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/eqz6uQ1rHpiVXMFou2iM4h/0

Answer (score 0):

According to the manual you can add desc to the group by list:
Example:
group by item1, item2 desc, item3

with or without rollup.

I've tried this and it works in Ubuntu version 5.5.58.  The reference page is:
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-modifiers.html

Answer (score -6):

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE GROUP BY numbers DESC;
```

This will give you last record from group.

Thanks

Comment: This doesn't answer the question. They want to order before grouping.