# MySQL GROUP BY and Descending

Tags: mysql, group-by

I've been trying to gather some data from a MySQL database for a while now.

The problem is that I want to group the data by `objectid` while getting only the newest data (Descending).

Everytime I try it, I either get an error, or it doesnt Descend.

My query at the moment is:

`SELECT * FROM 'table' GROUP BY 'objectid' DESC`

I've tried ordering by `id` or `timestamp`, but with an ascended result.

My question is similar to: `http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7306082/mysql-using-group-by-and-desc`

However the answers provided there didn't solve my problem.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

You also have to specify [ORDER BY](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/order-by-optimization.html) clause for sorting:

```
SELECT * FROM 'table' GROUP BY 'objectid' ORDER BY timestamp DESC
```

Comment: As i've said in the question, ORDER BY also outputs ascended results.

Answer (score 0):

your query is wrong you should make `backticks` instead of `single quotes`
and you missed order by statment

try this

```
     SELECT * FROM `table` GROUP BY `objectid` Order by id DESC
```

Comment: I've only used single quotes because `backticks` are used for different purposes on stackoverflow ;)

Answer (score 0):

This will give you the most recent entry per ObjectId, ordered by descending time; it simply left joins to find *all entries where there exists no newer entry for the same ObjectId*.

```
SELECT a.* 
FROM table1 a
LEFT JOIN table1 b
  ON a.ObjectId=b.ObjectId 
 AND a.time < b.time
WHERE b.ObjectId IS NULL
ORDER BY time DESC
```

[An SQLfiddle to test with](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/943c5/2).