# Order by clause is not working with group by in sql query

Tags: mysql

MYSQL query is getting data exactly as I want.But `ORDER BY` clause is not working.

But when I removed the `GROUP BY` from query then `ORDER BY` clause is work.

```
SELECT MESS. * , US. * , LF. *
    FROM messages MESS
    LEFT JOIN users AS US ON US.id = MESS.to_id
    LEFT JOIN label_infos LF ON LF.user_id = MESS.to_id
    WHERE MESS.frm_id =27
    OR MESS.to_id =27
    GROUP BY US.id
    ORDER BY MESS.id DESC
```

Comment: Just because MySQL allows this query does not mean you should use it. Read about aggregation and grouping.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [MySQL "Group By" and "Order By"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1066453/mysql-group-by-and-order-by)

Comment: Some example data & expected results would help here. But if there can be multiple MESS.id values for each US.id that you are grouping by - then it is indeterminate which value US.id you get back. The latest version of MySQL by default disallows non-aggregated columns being return unless you explicitly wrap them in ANY_VALUE().