# Order by not working as expected after using group by

Tags: mysql, laravel

I am attempting to get a list of messages, by grouping the `from_user_id` and `to_user_id` so they look like the screenshot below. Only, my problem is they do not seem to be ordering by the most recent.

Here's a screenshot showing how they look:

[image]

Query:
select

```
select 
concat(to_user_id, from_user_id) as group_by,
pm.*
from personal_messages pm
where (to_user_id = 1265) or (from_user_id = 1265)
group by group_by
order by id desc
```

Table Structure:

[image]

Comment: Since you tagged Laravel, why don't you try with eloquent?

Comment: @Jean-PhilippeMurray I am using Eloquent in my application, but using normal SQL queries to try and get the best outcome and then I'll convert that to Eloquent :)

Comment: I don't know your exact structure, but `PersonalMessage::where('to_user_id', 1265)->orWhere('from_user_id', 1265)->orderBy('created_at', 'desc')->get();` should do the trick.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to add the date value to the query:

```
select concat(to_user_id, from_user_id) as group_by,
       max(updated_at) as max_updated_at
from personal_messages pm
where (to_user_id = 1265) or (from_user_id = 1265)
group by group_by
order by max_updated_at desc
```

The date value could be `created_at` or `updated_at`, this depends on your actual requirement. You have to use an aggregate function like `MAX` though, because neither of these fields appears in the `GROUP BY` clause.

Comment: You can do `ORDER BY 2 DEC` also

Comment: @AkshayKhale It's a matter of personal taste I think. I personally don't find  this kind of syntax readable.

Comment: @GiorgosBetsos Thanks. I managed to adjust it slightly to get the result I wanted. I'll mark this as answered when I can.

Answer (score 1):

Check out answer [MySQL "Group By" and "Order By"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1066453/mysql-group-by-and-order-by)

The problem is the the group by has requirements for order that are trumping order_by.  There is not a 100% solution, but this link will give you something that should work for you.