# Mysql SELECT only unique values in one column when left joined with another table

Tags: mysql, select, distinct

This is the query:

```
SELECT a.id, a.userName,if(o.userId=1,'C',if(i.userId=1,'I','N')) AS relation 
       FROM tbl_users AS a 
       LEFT JOIN tbl_contacts AS o ON a.id = o.contactId 
       LEFT JOIN tbl_invites AS i ON a.id = i.invitedId 
  ORDER BY relation
```

This returns the output as follows:

```
+----+--------------+-------------+
| ID | USERNAME     | RELATION    | 
+----+--------------+-------------+
|  1 |          ray |           C | 
+----+--------------+-------------+
|  2 |         john |           I | 
+----+--------------+-------------+
|  1 |         ray  |           N | 
+----+--------------+-------------+
```

I need to remove the third row from the select query by checking if possible that id is duplicate. The priority is as follows:

C -> I -> N. So since there is already a "ray" with a C, I dont want it again with an I or N.

I tried adding distinct(a.id) but it doesn't work. How do I do this?

> > Why doesn't DISTINCT work for this?

Comment: What do you want to do with the relation? There's two different relations for `1 ray C/N` C and N.  Are you sure you want to throw that 3rd row away?

Comment: yes I'm sure. The priority is as follows C -> I -> N. So if there is a C with an userID then I dont want a N with that same userID

Comment: Can you help me mane? Any advice would be appreciated.

Comment: research MySQL [GROUP BY clause](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1066453/mysql-group-by-and-order-by).

Comment: `Why doesn't DISTINCT work for this?` -- err, where have you used DISTINCT?

Comment: yes I had. Like this: SELECT distinct(a.id).....

Comment: @SaeeshTendulkar Regarding your comment in your other question (tip: you can direct messages with @ and the name. Then I would've noticed it). It is a duplicate. The fact that you have to join a second or a third table, doesn't make this any different. It still works the same way. In your case you simply have to use MIN() instead of MAX() and before you do the subquery as in the accepted answer you join your tables. Simple as that.

Comment: I tried adding in "group by a.id" too but it cuts down some rows...I dont know how

Comment: I cant use MIN() or MAX() if it all depends on the letter .Whether it's a "C" or "N". And I tried all the duplicate question solutions...NOT WORK

Comment: @SaeeshTendulkar C comes before N in the alphabet, right? Then MIN() works.

Comment: @fancyPants I think it not exact duplicate of what you are tagged

Comment: @rams Why do you think so?

Comment: I cant form my query like it is done in the duplicated question.

Comment: @fancyPants  if the order is z - a - m then ?? it should not be replaced with min or max function right... there should be general solution

Comment: @rams. It's not indicated in the question, but it's a good point you made. Reopened and will answer the question.

Comment: @fancyPants Thank for your help mane. I appreciate it.

Comment: can you provide sample data of those 3 tables

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the specs you gave, all you have to do is group by ID and username, then pick the lowest value of relation you can find (since `C < I < N`)

```
SELECT a.id, a.userName, MIN(if(o.userId=1,'C',if(i.userId=1,'I','N'))) AS relation 
    FROM tbl_users AS a 
    LEFT JOIN tbl_contacts AS o ON a.id = o.contactId 
    LEFT JOIN tbl_invites AS i ON a.id = i.invitedId 
GROUP BY a.id, a.username
```

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple ways to get the group-wise maximum/minimum as you can see in this [manual page](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/example-maximum-column-group-row.html).

The best one suited for you is the first one, **if the order of the rows can not be defined by alphabetic order**.

In this case, given if the desired order were z-a-m (see Rams' comment) you'd need the [`FIELD()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html#function_field) function.

So your answer is

```
SELECT 
a.id, 
a.userName,
if(o.userId=1,'C',if(i.userId=1,'I','N')) AS relation 
FROM tbl_users a
LEFT JOIN tbl_contacts AS o ON a.id = o.contactId 
LEFT JOIN tbl_invites AS i ON a.id = i.invitedId 
WHERE 
if(o.userId=1,'C',if(i.userId=1,'I','N')) = (
    SELECT 
    if(o.userId=1,'C',if(i.userId=1,'I','N')) AS relation 
    FROM tbl_users aa
    LEFT JOIN tbl_contacts AS o ON aa.id = o.contactId 
    LEFT JOIN tbl_invites AS i ON aa.id = i.invitedId 
    WHERE aa.id = a.id AND aa.userName = a.userName
    ORDER BY FIELD(relation, 'N', 'I', 'C') DESC 
    LIMIT 1
)
```

Note, you can also do it like `ORDER BY FIELD(relation, 'C', 'I', 'N')` to have it more readable / intuitive. I turned it the other way round, because if you'd have the possibility of having a 'X' in the relation, the FIELD() function would have returned 0 because X is not specified as a parameter. Therefore it would be sorted before 'C'. By sorting descending and turning the order of the parameters around this can not happen.

Comment: Won't this query take a lot of time? It has "4 left joins"!!

Comment: This isn't necessarily bad. It depends on if you have created your tables with proper indexes. If you have this query won't make any trouble.