# I want the highest value to be on the top of the list

Tags: php, sql

So I have this query and display the value, the 'time' is integer, it is often updated by clicking and when it is updated I want the highest value si on the top of the list when page is refresh, but it's not, I wonder if the grouping affects the query?

```
$sql= "select * FROM message 
       where userid_to = '$UserLoggedIn' || userid_from = '$UserLoggedIn' 
       group by conversation_id 
       ORDER BY time DESC";
```

Comment: I used time function.

Comment: Putting parentheses around the assignment s might help.  The || has higher precedence than assignment.

Comment: The above query will give you only one row per conversation_id. So you will get one time per conversation_id. Are you using the group by on conversation_id to eliminate duplicates?

Comment: Your query is incorrect because you are aggregating by `conversation_id` but then you select all columns.

Comment: see this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/9797138/4020264. especially the important update.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you should be doing the aggregation on conversations inside a subquery to find the most recent time for each conversation.  Then join back to your `message` table to obtain the full message record.  I'm not sure what went wrong with your ordering, but your current query is not deterministic.

```
SELECT m1.*
FROM message m1
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT conversation_id, MAX(time) AS max_time
    FROM message
    WHERE userid_to = '$UserLoggedIn' OR userid_from = '$UserLoggedIn' 
    GROUP BY conversation_id
) m2
    ON m1.conversation_id = m2.conversation_id AND
       m1.time = m2.max_time
ORDER BY
    m1.time DESC;
```

Answer (score 0):

I would try doing it this way:

```
SELECT *,  MAX(time) as time
FROM message 
WHERE userid_to = '$UserLoggedIn' OR userid_from = '$UserLoggedIn'
GROUP BY conversation_id;
```

Comment: I wouldn't do it this way, becausd this query would not even run under certain configurations of MySQL (or on most other databases).

Comment: It should work on a standard configured MySQL DB. Can you provide examples to show me under what configurations this would not work?

Comment: Look into [ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/sql-mode.html#sqlmode_only_full_group_by) mode.

Comment: Will do. Thanks.