# Mysql query for getting count as per two grouping condition

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I have below data table and need to accomplish the result for Student count as per availability and per department

[image]
Note: Different Department may come in later.

Updated: 
Department Table:
[image]

Want to have result as below: (Student count as per availability and per department)

[image]

Comment: Hint:  `GROUP BY`.

Comment: what have you tried so far?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [MySQL "Group By" and "Order By"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1066453/mysql-group-by-and-order-by)

Comment: SELECT DISTINCT tblDept.DeptName, count(studid)  FROM tblDept,tblStud  where tblDept.DeptName= tblStud.DeptName group by  tblDept.DeptName  , this is only getting me the department wise final count, but i want to have the count as per the availability and department

Comment: I needed to get two parameters in the groupby.. i was giving only one.... I have got the desired result

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this could work,

```
SELECT Department, 
       CONCAT(Studavailability,', ',
              COUNT(*)) 
       as "Stud Count as per availability per department"
FROM Table
Group By Department, Studavailability
```