# How can I get last group of my data in my table? Codeigniter

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, codeigniter-3

I need to get the last group of my data. I already did `order_by` but still it did not produce my expected output

For visual reference here is what my table and its value are

[image]

So I need to get the last group of data, where in the `Capital of Australias` is repeated in id number `5` .

Here is my Model and my query.

```
public function view_results($id){
    $this->db->select('*');
    $this->db->from('results');
    $this->db->where('post_id', $id);
    $this->db->order_by('date_answered', 'DESC');
    $this->db->group_by('question');    
    $query = $this->db->get();
    return $result = $query->result_array();
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "last group"? Can you add the expected result to your question?

Comment: @El_Vanja - I group by the question and I am expecting to get the ids `5` to `8` which is the last group of the test.

Comment: @El_Vanja - As you know, I am only getting ids `1` to `4` which is the first group of the data.

Comment: [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35456144/4205384) should help.

Comment: @El_Vanja hello sir, can you kindly help me with the syntax? and the rest is for myself. just needed to get out of this problem please. thank you!

Comment: that's a very odd way to write a SQL statement... Please display the SQL statement as we don't know how you put the pieces together. Also, make clear what you mean by "the last group of my data"

Comment: @MannyRamirez He wants the latest answer for each question. Madara, can you please edit the question so we can see how you tried to create the subquery?