# sql groupby doesnt work, I want to be grouped by code_branch

Tags: php, sql, laravel

```
->select
(
  'a.status as status',
  'b.name as customer_name', 
  'e.name as branch_name' , 
  'c.name as company_name',
  'd.name as project_name',
  'f.name as region_name',
  'e.code as branch_code',
  'e.id as branch_code',
  DB::raw('COUNT(a.id) as total_transaksi')
)
->groupBy
(
  'e.id',
  'b.name',
  'e.name', 
  'e.code',
  'a.status',
  'c.name',
  'd.name',
  'f.name'
)
```

Comment: check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1066453/mysql-group-by-and-order-by

Comment: This doesn't look like PHP or SQL. Google gives me Laravel for `DB::raw`, so I've added that tag.

Comment: What happens when you run this code? Do you get an error message or wrong results? If an error message: Which? If a wrong result: In which way wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's incorrect, you can't use single name for same columns,

```
  'e.code as branch_code',
  'e.id as branch_code',
```

change to

```
  'e.code as branch_code',
  'e.id as branch_id',
```

Comment: i try and doesnt work

Comment: please in groupby use alias names.

Comment: No, don't; not all databases support it. Better to keep your SQL knowledge as widely applicable as possible rather than go down the "only mysql does this" rabbit hole

Comment: *you can't use single name* - [Databases don't care if you use same column aliases](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=f17b676df8139ad650774913dba80883)

Answer (score -1):

go to config/database.php

strict set false

Comment: This means something like "I rather want an incorrect result than getting an error message", correct?

Comment: i try , and doesnt work