# use both Group By and order by at same time in mysql/php

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by

Query

```
SELECT userid, lastseen 
FROM user_login_management 
GROUP BY userid 
ORDER BY lastseen DESC
```

when I use `group by` with `order by DESC` then `order by Desc` not work.

`userid` is duplicated record and I'm trying to fetch the value of the  latest row column named `lastseen` matching `userid` only.

If I use `GROUP BY userid` it well works and removes duplications but in this case, the `lastseen` column record is the first one of the matching id then I set `ORDER BY lastseen DESC` but it does not work.

If I use it without `GROUP BY` then it works. Is there any way to set `GROUP BY` on `userid` and `ORDER BY DESC` on`*lastseen` column?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [MySQL "Group By" and "Order By"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1066453/mysql-group-by-and-order-by)

Comment: You have no aggregate functions?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use an aggregate for your `lastseen` column:

```
SELECT userid, max(lastseen) as lastseen 
    FROM user_login_management 
    GROUP BY userid 
    ORDER BY lastseen DESC
```